# Combine 3 conditions in single Excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to create an excel formula:

1) if G17>G16, G16>G15, G15>G14, the data should "Pass";
2) if not, the data should "Fail"; and
3) if cells G14 to G17 is 0.00 it should show "NA".

At this stage I only have:

=IF(AND(G17>G16, G16>G15, G15>G14), "Pass", "Fail")

but the initial data gets flagged and shown as a "Fail" when I have not yet entered data. This is why cells G14 to G17 that is initially 0.00 should show "NA". I can't get a formula to work when I combine the three conditions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Formula:
`=IF(SUM(G14:G17)=0,"NA",IF(AND(G17>G16,G16>G15,G15>G14),"Pass","Fail"))`

You can change SUM(G14:G17)=0 to And if you prefer (And(G14=0,G15=0,G16=0,G17=0)) in case you have negative numbers in G14:G17
The formula will be:
`=IF(AND(G14=0,G15=0,G16=0,G17=0),"NA",IF(AND(G17>G16,G16>G15,G15>G14),"Pass","Fail"))`
It is a nested if